# Ошибка с sqlite3 python

Tags: python, sql, telebot, sqlite3

Начал работать с телеграмм ботом и sqlite3 на питоне и стокнулся с проблемой. Есть кусок кода:

```
def first_join(user_id, name, code, balance, firstname, lastname):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('base_ts.sqlite')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    row = cursor.execute(f'SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = "{user_id}"').fetchall()

    if len(row) == 0:
        cursor.execute(f'INSERT INTO users VALUES("{user_id}", "{name}", "{datetime.datetime.now()}", "{balance}", "{firstname}, "{lastname}")')
        conn.commit()
```

Он срабатывает когда юзер первый раз присоединяется к телеграмм боту, вот кстати дополнение кода:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
    def start(message):                     
        chat_id = message.chat.id
        func.first_join(user_id=chat_id, name=message.from_user.username, code=message.text[6:], balance=300, firstname=message.from_user.first_name,lastname=message.from_user.last_name)
```

Вот эти вот параметры:

```
message.from_user.id

message.from_user.first_name

message.from_user.last_name

message.from_user.username
```

Принадлежат модулю Telebot (api Telegram) с помощью которого можно получить разные параметры о человеке.

Моя проблема заключается в том что, при присоединение человека, срабатывает такая вот ошибка:

```
cursor.execute(f'INSERT INTO users VALUES("{user_id}", "{name}", "{datetime.datetime.now()}", "{balance}", "{firstname}, "{lastname}")')
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "None": syntax error
```

Я думаю что эта ошибка из-за того что у юзера нет фамилии и поэтому программа останавливается. Так как недавно начал изучать sqlite3 не разобрался что нужно делать, но опять же, это мое предположение. Что думаете?

Comment: Самое банальное - сделай `print` всех значений сразу перед строкой, вызывающей ошибку. Ты увидишь, какое из них имеет значение `None`. На сколько я понял, у тебя одно из полей базы данных определено как `not None`, но ты передаешь туда именно `None`. В этом случае либо менять структуру таблицы, либо используй тернарник для вывода альтернативного значения для None

Comment: None есть только в lastname, но как исправить это? Думал использовать "If exists" но не понимаю как, вообщем сижу думаю

Comment: я не отрицаю этого что возможно not None, но я вообще не понимаю что делать, хотя lastname и firstname я ставил TEXT

Comment: Есть тернарный оператор. используйте его. Например `f"...{lastname if not lastanme is None else ''}..."`

Comment: добавьте к вопросу код описания структуры базы данных. Ну или как именно вы создавали таблицы в базе.

Comment: c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (user_id TEXT, name TEXT, data TEXT, balance TEXT, firstname TEXT, lastname TEXT)")

Comment: У меня программа работает без firstname и lastname, но мне нужно с работать с этими параметрами и не знаю что за ошибка

Comment: а что писать после else , я думал можно написать pass, но там синтаксическая ошибка

Comment: У меня там пустая строка написана - две одинарных ковычки (апострофа)

Comment: Вот такая вот ошибка: SyntaxError: f-string: expecting '}'

Comment: Писал вот так:  cursor.execute(f'INSERT INTO users VALUES("{user_id}", "{name}", "{datetime.datetime.now()}", "{balance}", "{firstname}, "{lastname if not lastname is None else ''}")')

Comment: Ну да, у тебя там конфликт ковычек получается. Попробуй перед этим отдельно вычислить lastname, а затем подставлять уже готовое значение

Comment: всё получилось, сам напортачил, извините, можете добавить ваш ответ про тернарный оператор, я его отмечу как принятым

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В любом случае, лучше не делать это интерпояцией. В `sqlite3` это можно реализовать намного удобнее и элегантнее.

```
cursor.execute(
    'INSERT INTO users VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)',
    (
        message.from_user.id,
        message.from_user.username,
        datetime.datetime.now(),
        balance, 
        message.from_user.first_name,
        message.from_user.last_name,
    ),
)
```

А ошибка скорее всего из-за того, что в `sqlite3` нет слова `None` - вместо него - `NULL`

Answer (score 0):

***Ответом будет вот такой вариант записи:***

```
cursor.execute(f'INSERT INTO users VALUES("{user_id}", "{name}", "{datetime.datetime.now()}", "{balance}", "{firstname}", "{lastname if not lastname is None else ""}")')
```

***Спасибо*** - @cauf